# Why does /register redirect to home page if you are logged in on jhipster app?

Tags: angularjs, jhipster

I have a simple jhipster app.  I'd like to allow authenticated users to register accounts for new users.  I tried to do this by linked to /register.  The way it is configured, it will always redirect to the home page if you are already logged in (preventing you from accessing the register page).  I can't figure out where this behaviour is configured.  It works fine if you are not logged in.

My register.js is shown below

```
angular.module('myApp')
.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('register', {
            parent: 'account',
            url: '/register',
            data: {
                authorities: [],
                pageTitle: 'register.title'
            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/app/account/register/register.html',
                    controller: 'RegisterController'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                translatePartialLoader: ['$translate', '$translatePartialLoader', function ($translate, $translatePartialLoader) {
                    $translatePartialLoader.addPart('register');
                    return $translate.refresh();
                }]
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is coded in the authorize function of auth.service.js:

```
// an authenticated user can't access to login and register pages
if (isAuthenticated && ... $rootScope.toState.name === 'register')) {
   $state.go('home');
}
```

Comment: I'll add that as of jhipster 2.25.0 there is now create/delete user functionality on the user management page so accessing the registration page while you're logged in isn't as important as it used to be.